# jquery and if statment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How do I make this process in the correct way?
I want to show a message using jquery when if condition is true and other message when it is false.

```
<?php
if (in_array($id_patients, $rows)) {

  <script>
    jQuery(function () {
      $('#success_insert').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
  </script>
<?php
}else{ ?>
  <script>
    jQuery(function () {
      $('#failed_insert').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
  </script>
<?php }?>
```

Any idea about this?,please share it with me...

this is jquery

```
   $("#qsearch").on("submit", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "insert_visiting.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
 $("#inner_contant").append(data+"<br/>");                    },
                });
            });



})
```

Comment: Firstly you don't have a closing tag on your first `<?php`.

Comment: Have you imported the jQuery library?

Comment: the code of jquery is working but the problem is implemented all jquery inter condition, whether true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="success_insert" style="display: none;">Success</div>
<div id="failed_insert" style="display: none;">Failed</div>

<?php
$rows = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$id_patients = 12;
if (in_array($id_patients, $rows)) { ?>
  <script>
    jQuery(function () {
      $('#success_insert').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
  </script>
<?php
}else{ ?>
  <script>
    jQuery(function () {
      $('#failed_insert').fadeIn('slow').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
  </script>
<?php }?>
</body>
</html>
```

Note the closing php tag on the `if` line.

Comment: thank you very much i lost this `style="display: none;"`